# Error " Default export of the module has or is using private name" when performing nested export

Tags: javascript, typescript, node-modules

I'm  developing a **typescript common module** for some constants used in projects.

Here is my file structure

```
my-common
├── constants
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── status.ts
│   └── type.ts
├── dist
│   └── (compiled files)
├── index.ts
├── locales
│   ├── en
│   │   ├── index.ts
│   │   ├── status.ts
│   │   └── type.ts
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── fr
│   │   ├── index.ts
│   │   ├── status.ts
│   │   └── type.ts
│   └── zh-hk
│       ├── index.ts
│       ├── status.ts
│       └── type.ts
├── node_modules
│   └── (modules)
├── package.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

And there are example of the files

*constants/status.ts*

```
export enum UserStatus {
  INACTIVE = -1,
  NOT_VERIFIED = 0,
  VERIFIED = 1,
  ACTIVE = 10
}

export enum WorkspaceStatus {
  INACTIVE = -1,
  ACTIVE = 10
}
```

*locales/en/status.ts*

```
export enum UserStatus {
  INACTIVE = "Inactive",
  NOT_VERIFIED = "Not Verified",
  VERIFIED = "Verified",
  ACTIVE = "Active"
}

export enum WorkspaceStatus {
  INACTIVE = "Inactive",
  ACTIVE = "Active"
}
```

*constants/index.ts, locales/en/index.ts*

```
import * as status from "./status";
import * as type from "./type";

export { status, type };
```

*locales/index.ts*

```
import * as en from "./en";
import * as tc from "./zh-hk";
import * as fr from "./fr";

const obj = { en, fr, "zh-hk": tc };
export default obj;
```

*index.ts*

```
import * as constants from "./constants";
import locales from "./locales";

export default { ...constants, locales };
```

Typescript throws error in the *index.ts* export statement:

```
[ts] Default export of the module has or is using private name '"/path/to/module/locales/en/index"'.
[ts] Default export of the module has or is using private name '"/path/to/module/locales/fr/index"'.
[ts] Default export of the module has or is using private name '"/path/to/module/locales/zh-hk/index"'.
```

Any idea why there is such error and any solution for it.

Thanks.

EDIT:

when I change the export statement on *locales/index.ts* like this:

```
import * as en from "./en";
import * as tc from "./zh-hk";
import * as fr from "./fr";

export default { en, fr, "zh-hk": tc } as any;
```

It can now be exported, but there's no code completion in VSCode after I typed `common.locales.en`.